# bash while loop not cooperating?

Tags: bash, while-loop, sh

i am learning to script and created edit.sh to make a simple while loop, it is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh

a=0 

while [ $a -lt 10 ] 
do
echo $a
a='expr $a + 1'
done
```

i've googled this problem and most of the time its a spacing problem.... but i've checked and re writen the code some 10 times now and i always get

./edit.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments.

i cannot figure for the life of me what im doing wrong, its probably really stupid, i just cant see it, any help aprecciated. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With your code as it is written, you are assigning the literal string `expr $a + 1` to the name `a` on the first iteration, not the result of the command `expr 0 + 1`. With `$a` unquoted, you then try to execute the command `[ expr $a + 1 -lt 10 ]`, which does indeed have too many arguments.

The immediate issue is that you have mistaken backquotes for single quotes; you intended to write

```
a=`expr $a + 1`
```

However, backquotes should almost never be used, instead using the `$(...)` construct for command substitution.

```
a=$(expr $a + 1)
```

*However*, there is no need to use the `expr` command for arithmetic in POSIX-compliant shells. Use `$((...))` instead.

```
a=$((a + 1))
```

Comment: oh wow thanks! i didn't know, im just now learning this syntax and the video i watched did it the way i did it, i was pulling my hair out checking character by character what i was doing wrong lol. thanks!

Comment: Or `((a++))` of replace `while..` with `for ((a=0; a<10; a++)); do`.

Comment: Given the `sh` tag, I'm erring on the side of POSIX compatibility.